# How to make post view count on unique user using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, counter

I been searching on stackoverflow and I been trying a few example that I found but it's not working yet so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

Basically my current goal is to update the count column only on unique user. Currently the count increase when ever a user refresh their browser so I don't think that's the best way to do count view.

I've tried something like this but the view count is still increasing when ever I refresh the page.

```
<?php
  require_once '../config.php';
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  if (!isset($_SESSION['recent_posts'][$id])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE song SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = $id";
    $_SESSION['recent_posts'][$id] = 1;
}

  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: It's an interesting problem. You could the "session_id" in the table as "last_session_id", and if they don't match, increase the count and change "last_session_id" to the current. For "visitors" users outside of session or within a session, you can store cookies (with their permission if needed) with some other unique ID your code makes up.

Comment: post is accessible after login or we can access it without login as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using cookies.

```
<?php
  require_once '../config.php';
  $id = (int)$_GET['id'];


    if (!isset($_COOKIE['view_counted'])) {
        setcookie('view_counted', $id, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
        if (!isset($_SESSION['recent_posts'][$id])) {
            $sql = "UPDATE song SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = $id";
            $_SESSION['recent_posts'][$id] = 1;
        }
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

    }elseif (isset($_COOKIE['view_counted']) && $_COOKIE['view_counted'] != $id) {
        setcookie('view_counted', $id, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
        if (!isset($_SESSION['recent_posts'][$id])) {
            $sql = "UPDATE song SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = $id";
            $_SESSION['recent_posts'][$id] = 1;
        }
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
    }else{
        //you have already counted this as view.
    }


?>
```

Comment: What about a for a user already an account member of the app? And said user visits their favorite song 10 times in a row?

Comment: Hi, Arian. Thanks for this again. Quick question so “view_counted” and “recent_post” should be a column in my db table?

Comment: @mardubbles in that case it works, but if the user checks another song it won't work so I have to update the answer sorry about this mistake.

Comment: @ziico view_counted should not be a DB column neither recent_post

Comment: Can you check the updated answer now, hopefully i haven't forgot anything. @ziico this will remember the user for 30days, after 30 days it will count again. also i've corrected the $_GET['id'] it was vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: oh ok.. I think it might be working. The count increase only on the first view. I'll try to deploy to prod and test with other user now. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @ziico yes the increase only on the first view of each unique song id, only for 30 days after it will count again unless you change the cookie expiration days